# how to give asset path in laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package

I have developed laravel package. which has view example is here

**index.blade**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'ColdxLogistics') }} - @yield('title')</title>
    
        <meta name="description" content="Login page example">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!--end::Layout Skins -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('media/logos/favicon.ico')}}" /> 
      
    </head>
    
    
    <!--begin::Page Scripts(used by this page) -->
    <script src="{{asset('js/pages/crud/forms/editors/tinymce.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="{{asset('js/main.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    @yield('scripts')
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

You can here are many javascript and css files . I want to make asset folder for package from where ican load these files. like laravel have public directory.

Which Approach i should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not link to your packages assets folder, you need to publish the assets like in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#public-assets), then link to them normally using `asset()`.

In your packages service provider, you need to add:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/assets' => public_path('vendor/yourpackagename'),
    ], 'public');
}
```

Comment: if already folder is present what will that command do? because these are the same file js files which are already present in our laravel project. but if any other person will install this package he will not have this asset folder?

Comment: If the assets are essential for the package to function, you need to add them to the package, delete them from your project, and let the package publish them for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the Laravel documentation for this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#public-assets).

All you have to do is include your scripts like so: mix('style.css', 'vendor/your-package-name').

```html
<script src="{{mix('js/main.js', 'vendor/your-package-name')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```